Confused with the answer to "Dido's problem with an arclength constraint".
I was reading this post and I have problem understanding one of the answers. Here is the problem and the answer from the post:
The problem:
It is well known that the solution to the classical Dido problem is a semicircle, and that the solution to the classical isoperimetric problem is a circle. It's also reasonably obvious that the solution to the following variant is a circular arc:

Let $A$ and $B$ be fixed points on a plane, and let $l$ be a length greater than $\overline{AB}$. Which (smooth) curve through $A$ and $B$, of length $l$, maximises the area between itself and the line $AB$?

It's a straightforward exercise to verify extremality using the calculus of variations, but are there alternative proofs that do not invoke e.g. the Euler-Lagrange equations? This was originally a homework problem with the isoperimetric inequality given as a hint, and I'm just wondering what the intended solution was...
The answer:
This diagram might help:

For any length $l > \overline{AB}$, we can find a circle passing through $AB$ such that the length of a circular arc between $A$ and $B$ is equal to $l$. In the diagram above, suppose that the red, dotted arc $ADB$ and the upper part of the circle both have length $l$. Note that the region bounded by $ADBC$ (i.e.: the pink area) has the same perimeter length as the circle.

I'm not totally grasping the provided answer. I could deduce from the answer that given the fix length is $l+\overset{ \huge\frown}{ACB}$ we already know that the largest area that can be enclosed is a circle which is drawn in the image. Now we want to find the largest area enclosed by $l$. There is a unique way for subtracting the length $\overset{ \huge\frown}{ACB}$ from the circle which gives the arc above $AB$. But how we are sure that this region has the maximum area? Maybe at first we could enclose other shape with less area than the circle (with fixed perimeter $l+\overset{ \huge\frown}{ACB}$) but choose a smaller area with fixed perimeter $\overset{ \huge\frown}{ACB}$ to subtract ( the area be smaller than the arc below $AB$). Hence, we could have better optimum solution for maximizing the area with fixed perimeter $l$.

If the area enclosed by the curve $\ ADB\ $ and the line $\ AB\ $ were greater than that of the upper segment of the circle cut off by $\ AB\ ,$ then the closed curve $\ ADBCA\ $ would have the same perimeter as the circle, but enclose a larger area, thus contradicting the known result on the solution to the classical isoperimetric problem.
